# When I use 'Shift+B' to Zoom in to box, doesn't work

Tags: 3d-cursor

I have V 2.79. I've tried to use keyboard 'Shift+B'and it only has the dotted lines and doesn't form a Box. I've tried the View/Zoom Border command and it forms the Box, but zooms in on the Cursor. I've changed my User Preferences to Zoom to Mouse, and it still zooms to Cursor. Is there a bug in 2.79 that I don't know about? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this is happening but i can give you some ways that it MAY fix it. Blender uses a central orbiting camera movement, this means that if you have zoomed in too much, the camera will be at the origin of the orbital system. You can zoom out and in with your scroll wheel and you can also use 'SHIFT+CTRL+(- or +)'. Hope this helped, if it did not please reply as i will try my best to help you!

Comment: Well, I've got some good news. Now, if I go to View/Border Zoom, I can form a dotted square, then Enter to magnify the area. However, by simply pressing SHIFT+B, it will not work. Thanks for your solution, which also sorta works.